# AnimAll for UV animation + Particles

Tags: animation, particles

Aloha!

I'm trying to make a sprite animation (like this one, a blood splash from metal slug) in 2.79.

I can get easily the animation with Animall, it's just 10 frames.
The point is i need many of this, and i wanna use the particle system to achieve it, with its randomness.

[image]

When I go further it just shows the last frame. I can loop it, but every particle will show the same sprite.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve my goal? I wanna make every particle starts on its respective frame 0.

Thanks in advance!